# How to pass the value from Module A phtml file to Module B php file

Tags: magento2.4.1, google-api, magentomodule

I want to share one field from Module A to Module B,

I am trying, (Module B)

```
    $storeid = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123456789/locations?filter=storeCode="<?php
            echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Zero\Storelocator\Block\Neareststore")->setTemplate("Zero_Storelocator::google_reviews.phtml")->toHtml();
            ?>"';

    $url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/'.$accountId.'/locations/'.$storeid.'/reviews';
```

Logic: I want to get location id based on the store code, store code i am getting from Module A pass to Module B in **URL 1** and get location ID using API and pass that location Id to second url

The first step, How to pass my Module A phtml file value to Module B php file,

Any best practice pls suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it all in the template file, as it seems you're currently trying to do, is the wrong way. Is your custom block in "Module B" extending the relevant block from "Module A"? If so, the your block in "Module B" has all the same info as "Module A" block. All you have to do is know what method to call to get the information you want (assuming it's not a private method).

Let's assume that "Module A" has the block "Neareststore" (as in your example). Extending the block would be just like extending any other class in PHP:

```php
<?php

namespace VendorB\ModuleB\Block;

class NeareststoreB extends \VendorA\ModuleA\Block\Neareststore
{
}
```

Let's also assume that there's a protected (or public) method on Module A's "Neareststore" block called `getStoreCode`. You'd just update your layout to use your new custom block (`NeareststoreB`) and in your template file you'd call that method to get the desired value:

```php
<?php

$storeCode = $block->getStoreCode();
```

Now that you've got that info, you can do whatever you need with it.

That being said, if you're putting logic into your template file, you're not following best practices. Logic and processing should happen in the blocks. So if your ultimate goal is to get the store code from `Module A` then use that to execute a request to Google to get other information to construct a URL, you would be better of moving that logic to the block.

I'd create a method in the block called something like `getGoogleBusinessReviews`. That would then call the `getStoreCode` method of the parent block (from Module A) and execute the request to Google to get whatever information is necessary. Then I can either return the constructed URL string, or execute the request to Google and return Google's response as a variable to the template (either one works).

Example:

```php
<?php

namespace VendorB\ModuleB\Block;

class NeareststoreB extends \VendorA\ModuleA\Block\Neareststore
{
  public function getGoogleBusinessReviews() {
    // Get the nearest store's code from \VendorA\ModuleA\Block\Neareststore
    $storeCode = $this->getStoreCode();

    // Retrieve Google store ID
    $ch = curl_init('https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123456789/locations?filter=storeCode=' . $storeCode);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Assuming it responds with JSON
    $data = json_decode($result);

    // Construct the Google Business Reviews URL:
    $url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/' . $accountId . '/locations/' . $data['store_id'] . '/reviews';

    // Either fetch the value or return it and let the users browser do it
    return $url;
  }
}
```